# Reset Open Video Annotation after changing the div content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, annotations

I am working with open video annotation JavaScript library ([OVA](https://github.com/CtrHellenicStudies/OpenVideoAnnotation)) to annotate some content in a div tag. However, I would like to change the content of the div tag after page load "for example, using a text box and a button". The problem is that the annotation library does not work on the div content anymore (not on the text, nor on the video).

So, is there a functionality to reset the library to work again on the new content of the div tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got to solve my problem by destroying the plugin variable and then create a new instance.

The variable was initialized like this:

```
var ova = new OpenVideoAnnotation.Annotator($('#airlock'),options);
```

And I have destroyed it like this:

```
ova = null;
delete ova;
```

Then simply create a new instance of the variable:

```
var ova = new OpenVideoAnnotation.Annotator($('#airlock'),options);
```

And everything worked just fine.